# PHP Form submitting data except select option

Tags: php, mysql

I have the form, and submitting the data to the email.

Everything submitting except selection option.

Here is added my php code and form code.

I want to get the list from database, and placed them into selection option.

After submitting the form selected option should be sent.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $to = "synergyacademy2014@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
  $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
  $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $course = $_POST['course'];
  $subject = "Form submission";
  $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
  $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
  $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'] . $course;
  $headers = "From:" . $from;
  $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
  mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,$course);
  mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
  echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
  First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
  Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  Course: <select name="course">
    <option>Select Course</option>
    <option value="1">MBA</option>
    <option value="2">MCA</option>
  </select><br>
  Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: First is change your `<php` to `<?php`

Comment: Sorry! typing mistake that is

Comment: You do know that `1` or `2` will be passed on, and not `MBA` or `MCA`?

Comment: those are values right? want to get the list from database and placed them instead of options list

Comment: What is the name of your database? And table? And what API do you use? `mysql`, `mysqli`, `PDO`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch the list of options from the database, you can try using a loop. Be sure to have established a connection to the respective database-

```
<select name="course">
<?php

$tpl_options = "<option>Select Course</option>";

$query = "SELECT column FROM table [WHERE]";

$courses = mysql_query($query);

$i=1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($courses)){

$tpl_options .= "<option value='".$i."'>".$row['column']."</option>";

}

?>

</select>
```

Comment: It is displaying nothing

Comment: Yes yes got the list, But how to submit them?

Comment: Do u want the options to be submitted? As in...for <option value=1>MCA</option> do you want that MCA should be submitted to the database?

Comment: Whatever you want to submit should be the value...if you want to submit 1 then use value=1, if you want to submit MCA use <option value='".$row[column]."'>".$row[column]."</option>";

Answer (score 1):

- In order to get all the rows from your table and then assigning them to your `<select>` options, we need to determine first on what good API, like `mysqli` or `PDO`, to use.
- We need to determine first the database and table name that you need to establish the connection to your database.
- In the sample code below, we have selected `mysqli_*` [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Code:

```
<?php

  /* ESTABLISH FIRST YOUR CONNECTION; REPLACE NECESSARY DATA BELOW */
  $con = new mysqli("YourHost", "YourUsername", "YourPassword", "YourDatabase");
  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
  }

?>
```

After establishing your connection, we can now fetch data from your database.

```
Course: <select name="course"> <!-- START OF YOUR SELECT -->
  <?php

    /* REPLACE NECESSARY COLUMN NAMES AND TABLE NAME BELOW */
    if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id, course FROM course_table")){ /* PREPARE YOUR QUERY AND CHECK IF YOUR QUERY IS TRUE */
      $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
      $stmt->bind_result($id,$course); /* BIND THE RESULTS TO THESE VARIABLES */

      while($stmt->fetch()){ /* THEN WE GET ALL THE ROWS BASED FROM THE QUERY WE HAVE CREATED */
        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$course.'</option>'; /* STORE THE VALUES WE HAVE FETCHED TO THIS OPTIONS */
      } /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

      $stmt->close();
    } /* END OF YOUR PREPARED STATEMENT */

  ?>
</select>
```